# How to call Get Method with Send FromBody from Windows Application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have an API which accept the [FromBody] in get method So how I can call This Get Method

My API is

```
     [BearerAuth]
     [HttpGet]
     public Dictionary<long, string> GetEmployees([FromBody] Employee obj)
    {
        Dictionary<long, string> dic = new Dictionary<long, string>();

        //Some Implemenation

        return dic;
    }
```

Now I am trying to call it from windows Application

```
            using (WebClient webRequest = new WebClient())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee { EmpId = 1, Name = "Mohan", Gender = "Male", MobileNo = "9560498289", Salary = 50000 };
                string url = APIUrl_2 + "/APITest/GetMethod_FromBody";

                //string JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp);
                //ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                //byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(JsonString);

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + "AuthKey";
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {

                }
              }
```

Please Can anyone help me to send Employee Data in FromBody, It gets called but Employee is null.

I have to do it by get method only.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[FromBody]` attribute cannot be used for a `[HttpGet]` decorated method.
There are two possible modifications which you can do in order to fix your code:

1. First option: transform your method into a `POST` and send your employee object in the request body:

   ```
    [BearerAuth]
    [HttpPost]
    public Dictionary<long, string> GetEmployees([FromBody] Employee obj)
    {
       Dictionary<long, string> dic = new Dictionary<long, string>();

       //Some Implemenation

       return dic;
    }
   ```

And your client code:

```
     using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
     {
        //add authorization
        Employee emp = new Employee { EmpId = 1, Name = "Mohan", Gender = "Male", MobileNo = "9560498289", Salary = 50000 };
        string url = APIUrl_2 + "/APITest/GetMethod_FromBody";

        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp);

        string response = webClient.UploadString(url, jsonString);
     }
```

2. Second option: transform your [FromBody] into [FromUri] and send your employee object as query string

   ```
    [BearerAuth]
    [HttpGet]
    public Dictionary<long, string> GetEmployees([FromGet] Employee obj)
    {
       Dictionary<long, string> dic = new Dictionary<long, string>();

       //Some Implemenation

       return dic;
    }
   ```

The relevant part of the of the client:

```
webClient.QueryString.Add("EmptId", emp.EmpId);
webClient.QueryString.Add("Name", emp.Name);
webClient.QueryString.Add("Gender", emp.Gender);
...
string response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Thanks I understood this thing, But i thought we can use like we use in Post Method for get methof